# Receive and send a notification with Api laravel and ionic

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework

my goal is to receive and send a notification from the server side which is laravel, and i don't know how to do it. Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Laravel ships with a simple solution to API authentication
>   via a random token assigned to each user of your application. In your
>   config/auth.php configuration file, an api guard is already defined
>   and utilizes a token driver. This driver is responsible for inspecting
>   the API token on the incoming request and verifying that it matches
>   the user's assigned token in the database.

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication)

If you are a beginner and you are learning and figuring out how to make apis and secure them, [here](https://www.laravelplay.com/playlist/buidling-a-blog-application-with-laravel-56-and-ionic-v4.1) you can learn Buidling a Blog Application with Laravel 5.6 and Ionic v4.